# Dynamic Price Based on Customer Input

Tags: product, price, price-rules, dynamic-price

I'm Working on a Website That Sells WallPapers stickers
I want My Products to have Dynamic Prices as Follows:

- DropDown Which will specify the Material Of the wallpaper
- 2 text Fields ("Width", "Height")

and Based on The Material will Be the Multiply Value in the square space

Example:

Materials :

- (1) wallpaper = 5$ per 1 square feet
- (2) vinyl Sticker = 7$ per 1 square feet

so the price of a Product of Wallpaper material with width 5 and Height 6
will be ((5 * 6) * 5$)

any Idea how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can achieve this by setting the initial price of the product to zero and while adding the product to cart you can hook on the event sales_quote_add_item and write your observer model to do the calculation based on the selection on the product details page. Once the total price of the product is calculated you can use the method setOriginalCustomPrice() against the quote item an pass the price to this method like $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($calculated_price);

The whole process will take time to explain, but this can give you a starting point.

Thanks.

Comment: I understand but since i'm Newbi in Magento Development
Please Try to provide full explanation or tutorial or any resource

Comment: Please Provide little detailed explanation if u can